Looking for an Offline Text-to-Speech Engine with Realistic Urdu Voice for Android
I am working on an Android application that requires converting Urdu text into speech using a realistic and offline-supported voice. Here’s what I have tried so far:
Google Text-to-Speech (TTS) Engine:
I successfully integrated it and downloaded the Urdu language pack for offline usage.
However, the voice quality is not realistic enough for my application's requirements.
Other Open-Source Solutions:
I explored options like RHVoice and eSpeak NG, but the voice still sounds robotic or unnatural.
I need a TTS engine or library that meets the following criteria:
Offline Support: Must work without an internet connection.
Language: Supports Urdu.
Voice Quality: Provides realistic, human-like voice synthesis.
Platform: Compatible with Android.
If no ready-made solution exists, I am open to suggestions for:
Porting a Linux-based TTS engine to Android.
Using a pre-trained neural model (e.g., Tacotron 2, FastSpeech) optimized for Android.
Has anyone encountered a similar requirement or found a solution for realistic Urdu TTS in offline mode on Android? Any guidance or recommendations are highly appreciated.

Quoting the site documentation, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow".
